# @Autowired and bean creation order

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Is it possible to avoid @Autowire some beans until other depeandant beans have been created? Let me explain it better with an example:

I have a FactoryBean that creates an object of type *A* that has a property called *a*. If the property is null it assigns a default value to the bean *A*.

In a @Configuration class I have:

```
    @Autowired
    private A myBean;
```

What is happening is that the factory creates the bean (I don't fully understand how) but the field *a* in the factory is null and I need that it takes another bean that it's used to create *A*. I can't add any annotation to the Factory since it's inside of an external dependency.

The thing is that I need to set the value of *a* before the @Autowired requests the object to the factory. Is it possible given the restrictions I have?

**edit**
Heres the code:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:factory-context.xml")
public class ServiceContextConfig {
    @Autowired
    private A createdObject;

    @Bean(name = "entities-list")
    public List<String> getEntity() {
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        ls.add("countriescatalog");
        return ls;
    }
```

Then the factory-context.xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="client-factory" class="ClientFactory">
    <property name="entities" ref="entities-list"/>
</bean>
```

Actually the configuration is a little bigger. I didn't try with a simplified example like this. I'll try to reproduce it with a simplified context like this and see if I can fix it wrapping the factory as @emd suggested

Comment: Please show the how your factory creates your bean, eg. the `<bean>` declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood the question right. But here an example what you can do:

Wrap the factory in your own factory. Autowire that field in you own factory. Construct the object with the original factory, inject the field and return the object.

Example:

```
public class MyFactory {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    private final OriginalFactory originalFactory;

    public MyFactory(OriginalFactory originalFactory) {
        this.originalFactory=originalFactory;
    }

    public CreateObject getInstance() {

        CreatedObject createdObject = originalFactory.getInstance();
        createdObject.setA(a);

        return createdObject;
    }
}
```

Spring part:

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="aa.aa.MyFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="originalFactory" />  
</bean>         
<bean id="createdObject" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

Comment: Actually the problem was a little trickier and wasn't showed in the question. The problem was a circular reference caused because A was implementing ApplicationListener and the factory was reporting an application event. So A was registered as listener of the factory that was creating A. Anyway @emd response helped me to understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I am assuming that the `@Autowired A createdObject` is dependent on the `@Bean "entities-list"`, but `createdObject` is being autowired before `"entities-list"` has been created.

I have run into a similar issue and found a solution.

In any particular `@Configuration` class, Spring first resolves all `@Autowired` fields before adding any `@Bean` methods to the context. However, any beans in the `@Import` list will be added to the context before the `@Autowired` fields are resolved.

Therefore, we can work around our problem by creating an inner-configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ServiceContextConfig.InnerConfig.class)   // <-- don't forget to add here 
@ImportResource("classpath:factory-context.xml")
public class ServiceContextConfig {
    @Autowired
    private A createdObject;

    @Configuration
    static class InnerConfig {     // <-- wrap bean in an "inner-configuration"
        @Bean(name = "entities-list")
        public List<String> getEntity() {
            List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
            ls.add("countriescatalog");
            return ls;
        }
    }
}
```

This is especially helpful if you are unable to edit the other configuration, `factory-context.xml`.